# Wordpress and PHP 5.5 - WebP conversion for all images?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, php-5.5, webp

Good day. I need to optimize the images in the website, converting PNG/JPEG to webP format.

I tried several plugins like : Kraken, Shortpixel, Optimus, EWWW Optimizer, WP Smush, Imagify, WebP Express but none of this is available unless you pay for them. ( Exception for EWW Optimizer, webP express - free, but they require PHP 5.6 and upper, whereas the website is deployed in PHP 5.5 )

Is there any suggested plugin / solution ? I've also thinked of settings in side the .htaccess file and then serve the webP images, but the content writer will have to convert the images themselves ( so this is not optimal at all )

Comment: you should try webP express and ask your server guy to update the php version as its no major difference so website will work after updation

Comment: thank you :( I'll try to convince him, as several sites are running in the same server, he afraid updating the PHP version cause issues for the others

Comment: I've made a package to use the EWWW api, but it is written with a base of PHP 7.1. You could fork it and take some of the elements out that are not supported in PHP5.5. e.g. the scalar type hinting etc https://github.com/townsymush/ewww-client